# Query works perfect in phpmyadmin but only returns true/1 when fetching with php

Tags: mysql

I have this query that does exactly what i want in phpmyadmin, it returns the number of visits my site has had. ex: visitorCount: 2204

```
set @last_uid = 0;
set @last_tm = '00:00';
set @last_vid = 0;

SELECT MAX(
     CASE WHEN @last_uid = visitorid AND cast( @last_tm as datetime) >= subtime( timestamp, '01:00' )
     THEN 
          if( (@last_tm := timestamp ), @last_vid, @last_vid)
     ELSE 
          if( (@last_uid := visitorid) + (@last_vid := @last_vid+1) +(@last_tm := timestamp ),@last_vid, @last_vid )
     END 
) as visitorCount

FROM visits v
ORDER BY timestamp DESC, visitorid
```

When i try to execute this query from PHP however it doesen't work, i have tested with a regular php mysql connection and with cakephp $this->Model->query(); without any success, all i get from the query is "1" or true. Whats wrong?

```
$query = "set @last_uid = 0;
                    set @last_tm = '00:00';
                    set @last_vid = 0;

                    SELECT MAX(
                         CASE WHEN @last_uid = visitorid AND cast( @last_tm as datetime) >= subtime( timestamp, '01:00' )
                         THEN 
                              if( (@last_tm := timestamp ), @last_vid, @last_vid)
                         ELSE 
                              if( (@last_uid := visitorid) + (@last_vid := @last_vid+1) +(@last_tm := timestamp ),@last_vid, @last_vid )
                         END 
                    )

                    FROM visits v
                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC, visitorid";

        $con = mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass");
        if (!$con) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        print_r(mysql_fetch_row($result));
```

Gives me the error message:

```
mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Comment: Just Google the error message. Your query fails and returns `false`

Comment: It doesen't fail in phpmyadmin as i said, i have executed multiple other querys in my php code without any problems so thats not the problem either.

Comment: So you're sure this query doesn't fail because *other* queries in your code don't fail?

Comment: I cant see why it would fail when its working in phpmyadmin? Please give me a hint if you have any idea. I only said that other querys works well with my php to rule out a faulty database connection.

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to find out what error message the query fails with. (You seem to be doing that below already?)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @ last_tm = 00:00; set @last_vid = 0; ' at line 2

Comment: Ah, of course - you can't pass multiple commands through `mysql_query()`. That's what the answerer below is trying to address. Not sure how to fix it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is because you are executing multiple statements but try combining it into one,

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN @last_uid = visitorid AND cast( @last_tm as datetime) >= subtime( timestamp, '01:00' )
                THEN if((@last_tm := timestamp), @last_vid, @last_vid)
                ELSE if((@last_uid := visitorid) + (@last_vid := @last_vid+1) + (@last_tm := timestamp), @last_vid, @last_vid )
            END)
FROM    visits v,
        (SELECT @last_uid := 0, @last_tm := '00:00', @last_vid := 0;) x
ORDER   BY timestamp DESC, visitorid
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the comment! Your query gives me the following error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: I removed the ";" from @ last_tm := '00:00', @last_vid := 0;) x and now its working! =)